# Nice borders/boxes on items in LinearLayout like Facebook Android App?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

For Android application development, how would I go by borders for each element in the LinearLayout natively. As an example below, Facebook has this type of border for each wall post in your news feed - a darker colour for the background with a lighter colour boxes for each Wall Post. Thanks!

Facebook News Feed with nice borders:
https://lh6.ggpht.com/tea1nQyiBlPzEw1dNf5R_rwdEkWDvS45FD76_-SRLfLQBpl_izPK7rtPLEX-N-f9ONQ3=h900-rw

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.41"
android:background="#ccc" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.45"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.45"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following line to layout:

```
android:layout_margin="20dp"
```

The structure in xml will be like

```
<Layout1>
   <Layout2>
   </Layout2>
</Layout1>
```

Set layout1 background as gray and give margin to layout2.